# Dockerized django app in office network

Tags: networking, nginx, python, django

I have django app launched with gunicorn on 0.0.0.0:8000 behind nginx as a reverse proxy listened on 1337 port.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: gunicorn myapp.wsgi:application --name myapp --log-file - --log-level info --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./web-backend/src/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - .env_web
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:11.5-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - .env_db

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 1337:80
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

with nginx.conf:

```
upstream myapp {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myapp;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

}
```

The application is naturally reachable from localhost both at 8000 and 1337, however I would like it to be also reachable from all hosts in a different network (Info below).

Some info:
Django app host which I am able to connect with ssh: 10.157.100.98/24
whereas the eth0 on the host itself is 192.168.0.13/24 which I believe will in the future have opened port for the internet, but for now just to have possibility for all users in 10.157.100.0 network to access the app.

Tracert:

```
Tracing route to 10.157.100.98 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     5 ms     4 ms     5 ms  10.156.80.1
  2     5 ms     4 ms     6 ms  172.30.237.241
  3     3 ms     3 ms     4 ms  172.30.225.6
  4     4 ms     4 ms     4 ms  172.30.225.6
  5    23 ms    23 ms    23 ms  135.7.192.30
  6    42 ms    42 ms    42 ms  135.7.192.7
  7    42 ms    43 ms    43 ms  135.7.193.21
  8    43 ms    43 ms    43 ms  sth-vlan478-domain.net [172.30.8z.x1]
  9    43 ms    43 ms    43 ms  sth2-vlan20-domain.net [172.30.8z.x2]
 10    43 ms    44 ms    44 ms  sth3-vlan22-domain.net [172.30.8z.x3]
 11    43 ms    45 ms    43 ms  172.30.8z.x4
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14    43 ms    42 ms    45 ms  10.157.100.98

Trace complete.
```

route

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
instance-data.e 192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.30.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-df38aebf18b9
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

iptables

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             sth5-vlan401-domain.net tcp dpt:postgresql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             sth6-certr01-domain.net tcp dpt:8000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.30.0.5           tcp dpt:http

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

route
'''
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
instance-data.e 192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.30.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-df38aebf18b9
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

'''
```

I would like to point out that i am a complete newbie when it comes to networking. So:

1. I am connecting via 172.30.86.42 to my django app server, so in order to enable all users (who will also connect via that proxy) to access application by 10.157.100.98:8000 or 1337 I need to open those ports for that interface, am I correct? Is there anything more?
2. Should anyone feel free to demonstrate how the traffic goes bit by bit, I believe it would be beneficial for all newbies.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved... I had Nginx listen on 1337 instead of 80 which was actually opened via security group in OpenStack.